# Trying to read temperature, but always reading 655.000000 from Si7021 sensor connected to STM32 NUCLEO-F746ZG via I2C

Tags: stm32, sensor, i2c, c, stm32cubeide

I am trying to read temperature and humidity data from the [Si7021](https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/Si7021-A20.pdf) temperature and humidity sensor on an STM32 NUCLEO-F746ZG over I2C, and then send it over UART to be viewed on a computer. After connecting the sensor to the board, and loading the below code (CubeIDE), I am not able to get temperature measurements from the sensor.

**Update: When I use the debugger in CubeIDE, and step into the `si7021_measure_temperature(&hi2c1)` function, and step over each step, `temp` and `tempC` actually update with the correct temperature. However, if I step over the `si7021_measure_temperature(&hi2c1)` function while debugging, I still get the error. This makes me think it may be a clock error.**

I am using the Si7021 library found [here](https://github.com/belyalov/stm32-hal-libraries/blob/master/doc/si7021.md).

Firstly, I configured PB9 and PB8 for I2C communication:

[image: PB8 and PB9 configured at SCL and SDA, respectively.]

I then connected the sensor to the board (10k pull up resistors on SDA and SCL):

`VIN` --> `3.3v`, `GND` --> `GND`, `SDA` --> `PB9`, `SCL` --> `PB8`.

I imported the library into my project, and included it in `main.c` with `#include "si7021.h"`.

Within `int main(void)`, I have this code:

```
HAL_Init();
SystemClock_Config();
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_ETH_Init();
MX_USART3_UART_Init();
MX_USB_OTG_FS_PCD_Init();
MX_I2C1_Init();

uint8_t buffer[12];
```

Within the `while(1)` loop, I have the following code:

```
uint32_t temp = si7021_measure_temperature(&hi2c1);
float tempC = temp/100;
sprintf((char*)buffer, "%f\r\n", tempC);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3, buffer, strlen((char*)buffer), 100); 
HAL_Delay(100);
```

This code compiles and uploads to the board without errors. When inspecting the data sent over serial to the computer via the serial monitor, all I get is repeated "655.000000" which is an error code in the library:

[image: The output from Serial is always 655.000000]

I tried the sensor with an Arduino, using example code, and it connects and reads temperature fine, so I know the sensor is not faulty. I also manually set `temp = 1200`, and 12 was successfully printed in the serial monitor, so I know UART is configured correctly.

Anything else I can check that may be configured incorrectly, which is stopping me from reading temperature from the sensor?

Edit: Below are my clock settings in case that is relevant too.

[image: Clock settings]

Edit 2: [pictures url](https://imgur.com/a/txCaPHw)

Comment: Did u add pullup resistors to PB8 and PB9?

Comment: @Rodo I just added 10kOhm pull up resistors between SDA and 3.3v, and SCL and 3.3v, and nothing has changed :(

Comment: @p1unge Those pullup resistors are necessary for I²C to work.

Comment: 10kOhm sounds to be on the high side. Try something like 6k2.

Comment: The 32F746G DISCOVERY board has 2.7k pullup resistors.

Comment: @Rodo so I shouldn't need external resistors?

Comment: I have also updated the post with my clock settings in case that's part of the problem.

Comment: @p1unge: You do because you are not using the  32F746G DISCOVERY board. You have the simpler version NUCLEO board with the same MCU. I was just telling you what ST is using.

Comment: Please add a picture of your board setup... no matter how messy it looks.

Comment: @Rodo, I've edited the post with an Imgur link to some photos of the board. Thanks.

Comment: I am currently using 10k resistors, I'll see if I have anything smaller tomorrow.

Comment: The library signals you an error by returning 65535. You don't check for any errors and divide that to 655.0 and print it. Since you have a debugger, you can debug the code to see where and why it returns with an error. But the library still does not give you info what the I2C layer returned as error so you need to check there. You also don't show any MCU init code, so we don't even know if the I2C init or GPIO init are even called to use the I2C.

Comment: @Justme thanks for the advice. I used the debugger, and when I stepped into the si7021_measure_temperature() function, then over each step in the function, I am able to get the temp correctly. When I step over this function, I get the same error code. Any idea why reading from the sensor only works wile debugging?

Comment: @Rodo I am now using 5.1k pull up resistors. Like I mentioned in the updates to my original post and in the above comment, I am able to get a temperature reading when stepping into the si7021_measure_temperature() function, and step over each step in the function. When returning to the main, a temperature is printed to serial successfully.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a bug, that's a feature, and you are likely not always getting 655.0 but sometimes a correct result.

Single stepping makes it obvious.

The library is using "No Hold" type temperature read command, which means that it will not respond to any I2C operation while performing the temperature measurement and conversion internally.

That is backed by the fact that when single stepping the code, the conversion of temperature can complete and the chip can respond with a result due to delay.

In any case, please debug why I2C funtions, does not return with OK, and what is the reason they return with, and if it is an error, check what the error code is. Maybe try increasing the delays in the driver.

The driver should be more verbose that when there is an error, it should give more info what the error is. But such are most pieces of code you find on the net, because hey, it worked for the person who made it.